# Unexpected anchor value, expected a negative anchor in Compose app release builds

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-accompanist

I'm using Kotlin 1.6.21, compose 1.2.0-alpha08 and accompanist 0.24.7-alpha in my project. When building a project with release build (both using and not using R8), my app crashes immediately on start, and I've been unable to find a workaround for this. I'm including a stack trace, it contains almost no lines of my app's code.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Compose Runtime internal error. Unexpected or incorrect use of the Compose internal runtime API (Unexpected anchor value, expected a negative anchor). Please report to Google or use https://goo.gle/compose-feedback
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerKt.composeRuntimeError(Composer.kt:4215)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.SlotWriter.moveSlotGapTo(SlotTable.kt:3472)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.SlotWriter.insertSlots(SlotTable.kt:2582)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.SlotWriter.insertAux(SlotTable.kt:1366)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.sourceInformation(Composer.kt:3067)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerKt.sourceInformation(Composer.kt:1075)
        at androidx.compose.material.ScaffoldKt.rememberScaffoldState(Unknown Source:8)
        at com.nek12.test.ui.screens.home.HomeScreenKt.HomeScreen(HomeScreen.kt:54)
        at com.nek12.test.ui.screens.destinations.HomeScreenDestination.Content(HomeScreenDestination.kt:26)
        at com.ramcosta.composedestinations.animations.AnimatedNavHostEngine.CallComposable(AnimatedNavHostEngine.kt:256)
        at com.ramcosta.composedestinations.animations.AnimatedNavHostEngine.access$CallComposable(AnimatedNavHostEngine.kt:57)
        at com.ramcosta.composedestinations.animations.AnimatedNavHostEngine$addComposable$1.invoke(AnimatedNavHostEngine.kt:166)
        at com.ramcosta.composedestinations.animations.AnimatedNavHostEngine$addComposable$1.invoke(AnimatedNavHostEngine.kt:165)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:135)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at com.google.accompanist.navigation.animation.AnimatedNavHostKt$AnimatedNavHost$9$1.invoke(AnimatedNavHost.kt:212)
        at com.google.accompanist.navigation.animation.AnimatedNavHostKt$AnimatedNavHost$9$1.invoke(AnimatedNavHost.kt:210)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.saveable.SaveableStateHolderImpl.SaveableStateProvider(SaveableStateHolder.kt:84)
        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt.SaveableStateProvider(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:60)
        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt.access$SaveableStateProvider(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:1)
        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt$LocalOwnersProvider$1.invoke(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:52)
        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt$LocalOwnersProvider$1.invoke(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:51)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt.LocalOwnersProvider(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:47)
        at com.google.accompanist.navigation.animation.AnimatedNavHostKt$AnimatedNavHost$9.invoke(AnimatedNavHost.kt:210)
        at com.google.accompanist.navigation.animation.AnimatedNavHostKt$AnimatedNavHost$9.invoke(AnimatedNavHost.kt:202)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:135)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedContentKt$AnimatedContent$5$1$4.invoke(AnimatedContent.kt:658)
        at androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedContentKt$AnimatedContent$5$1$4.invoke(AnimatedContent.kt:648)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:116)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedVisibilityKt.AnimatedEnterExitImpl(AnimatedVisibility.kt:937)
        at androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedVisibilityKt.AnimatedVisibility(AnimatedVisibility.kt:606)
        at androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedContentKt$AnimatedContent$5$1.invoke(AnimatedContent.kt:638)
        at androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedContentKt$AnimatedContent$5$1.invoke(AnimatedContent.kt:625)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedContentKt.AnimatedContent(AnimatedContent.kt:671)
        at com.google.accompanist.navigation.animation.AnimatedNavHostKt.AnimatedNavHost(AnimatedNavHost.kt:197)
        at com.google.accompanist.navigation.animation.AnimatedNavHostKt.AnimatedNavHost(AnimatedNavHost.kt:91)
        at com.ramcosta.composedestinations.animations.AnimatedNavHostEngine.NavHost(AnimatedNavHostEngine.kt:82)
        at com.ramcosta.composedestinations.DestinationsNavHostKt.DestinationsNavHost(DestinationsNavHost.kt:60)
        at com.nek12.test.ui.testNavigationKt$testNavigation$1.invoke(testNavigation.kt:29)
        at com.nek12.test.ui.testNavigationKt$testNavigation$1.invoke(testNavigation.kt:28)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.material.ModalBottomSheetKt$ModalBottomSheetLayout$1.invoke(ModalBottomSheet.kt:330)
        at androidx.compose.material.ModalBottomSheetKt$ModalBottomSheetLayout$1.invoke(ModalBottomSheet.kt:326)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:116)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxWithConstraintsKt$BoxWithConstraints$1$1$measurables$1.invoke(BoxWithConstraints.kt:69)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxWithConstraintsKt$BoxWithConstraints$1$1$measurables$1.invoke(BoxWithConstraints.kt:69)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutNodeSubcompositionsState$subcompose$2$1$1.invoke(SubcomposeLayout.kt:753)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutNodeSubcompositionsState$subcompose$2$1$1.invoke(SubcomposeLayout.kt:447)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ActualJvm_jvmKt.invokeComposable(ActualJvm.jvm.kt:74)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:3164)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:3154)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt__DerivedStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(DerivedState.kt:252)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(Unknown Source:1)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.doCompose(Composer.kt:3154)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.composeContent$runtime_release(Composer.kt:3091)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.composeContent(Composition.kt:568)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.composeInitial$runtime_release(Recomposer.kt:811)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$CompositionContextImpl.composeInitial$runtime_release(Composer.kt:3683)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.setContent(Composition.kt:503)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutNodeSubcompositionsState.subcomposeInto(SubcomposeLayout.kt:467)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutNodeSubcompositionsState.subcompose(SubcomposeLayout.kt:440)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutNodeSubcompositionsState.subcompose(SubcomposeLayout.kt:431)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutNodeSubcompositionsState.subcompose(SubcomposeLayout.kt:420)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutNodeSubcompositionsState$Scope.subcompose(SubcomposeLayout.kt:715)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxWithConstraintsKt$BoxWithConstraints$1$1.invoke-0kLqBqw(BoxWithConstraints.kt:69)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxWithConstraintsKt$BoxWithConstraints$1$1.invoke(BoxWithConstraints.kt:67)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutNodeSubcompositionsState$createMeasurePolicy$1.measure-3p2s80s(SubcomposeLayout.kt:581)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerPlaceable.measure-BRTryo0(InnerPlaceable.kt:44)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode$performMeasure$1.invoke(LayoutNode.kt:1388)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode$performMeasure$1.invoke(LayoutNode.kt:1387)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot$Companion.observe(Snapshot.kt:2063)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:112)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:78)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeMeasureSnapshotReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:66)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.performMeasure-BRTryo0$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:1387)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable.remeasure-BRTryo0(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:94)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable.measure-BRTryo0(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:75)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.measure-BRTryo0(LayoutNode.kt:1331)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.RootMeasurePolicy.measure-3p2s80s(RootMeasurePolicy.kt:38)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerPlaceable.measure-BRTryo0(InnerPlaceable.kt:44)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode$performMeasure$1.invoke(LayoutNode.kt:1388)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode$performMeasure$1.invoke(LayoutNode.kt:1387)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot$Companion.observe(Snapshot.kt:2063)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:112)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:78)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeMeasureSnapshotReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:66)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.performMeasure-BRTryo0$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:1387)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable.remeasure-BRTryo0(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:94)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.remeasure-_Sx5XlM$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:1341)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.doRemeasure-sdFAvZA(MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:185)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.remeasureAndRelayoutIfNeeded(MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:274)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.access$remeasureAndRelayoutIfNeeded(MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:38)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.measureAndLayout(MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:208)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.onMeasure(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:789)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25774)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView.internalOnMeasure$ui_release(ComposeView.android.kt:298)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView.onMeasure(ComposeView.android.kt:285)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25774)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6980)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25774)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6980)
        at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:463)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25774)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6980)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:761)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25774)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:3628)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:2424)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2694)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:2143)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8670)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1037)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:845)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:780)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1022)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:550)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
```

I've commented on [this bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/204897513) on google's issue tracker, but not only it hasn't been fixed in 3+ months, but it also seems eerily similar, but not exactly my problem because my stacktrace doesn't have anything inlined in it...

How do I solve this problem, and why has no one filed a bug report on this before me? My release build of the app is literally unusable until it is fixed.

UPD: Some more details:
Here is the call site of the rememberScaffoldState()

```
@Composable
@Destination(start = true)
fun HomeScreen(
    navigator: DestinationsNavigator,
) = MVIComposable(getViewModel<HomeViewModel>()) { state ->

    val scaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState()
    val context = LocalContext.current
```

Here are the contents of my navigation composable

```
    val navHostEngine = rememberAnimatedNavHostEngine(
        //TODO: Customize
        rootDefaultAnimations = RootNavGraphDefaultAnimations.ACCOMPANIST_FADING,
    )
    val navController = rememberAnimatedNavController()
    val bottomSheetNavigator = rememberBottomSheetNavigator()
    navController.navigatorProvider += bottomSheetNavigator

    //Wrap entire app in a bottom sheet in order to navigate to bottom sheets with destinations
    RBottomSheet(bottomSheetNavigator) {
        DestinationsNavHost(navGraph = NavGraphs.root, engine = navHostEngine, navController = navController)
    }
```

Comment: Are you saying the issue does not come up in the debug build? Also, have you started an issue on the Compose Issue tracker?

Comment: Yes, this issue is not present in Debug builds. 
No, I just commented under the issue linked in the main post

Comment: Consider starting a new issue, and link it here so others can star it if they face something similar. Nobody here seems to be familiar with a solution, it seems, or it definitely would have been answered by now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TL;DR:
Don't use inline functions with compose. At least not until this is fixed

I solved the issue by examining my dependencies. One of the dependencies transitively used an inline function somewhere in the composition, and it produced the error. I had to remove the dependency. Apparently it really was that issue with inline from the google's issue tracker.